# Separate subdomains on one GitHub page

Tags: github, subdomain, hosting, github-pages

I'm looking to host two very different sections of my website in the same GitHub Pages site. For example, say I a section of my website hosts cat videos, and one that hosts dog videos, and both are light enough to fit within the limits of my Pages repo.

What I want is for the link `meow.example.com` to take you to the cat section of the page, and `bark.example.com` to take you to the dog section of the site. This is of course assuming I already own the `example.com` domain on GoDaddy or whatever other domain registrar.

I know for a fact that this can be done (ex: `en.wikipedia.org` vs `es.wikipedia.org`). Is this possible to do with GitHub Pages? If not, what would I be required to do with another hosting service?